# What if $x$ is in terms of function of $n$, in the expansion of $e^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, exponential-function

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1+ \frac{x}{n})^n =e^x$
(is also obtained using binomial expression.)

Then I suspect $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+ \frac{f(n)}{n}\right)^n =  e^{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(n)}$$

Is this true for any function $f(n)$ ?

Or is it true for some specific kinda function? $\,$ [clearly for constant function]

Comment: This is an interesting idea, have you tried any specific functions to see the results?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$, assuming it exists. We will show that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(1 + \frac{f(n)}{n} \bigg)^n = e^f$$

By definition of the limit, this is equivalent to the statement that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 $, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n \ge N$,

$$\Bigg| \bigg(1 + \frac{f(n)}{n} \bigg)^n - e^f \Bigg| < \varepsilon$$

---

By the continuity of $\text{exp}$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $|x-f|<\delta \implies |e^x-e^f| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Since $f(n) \to f$, there exists $N_1$ s.t. $\forall n \ge N_1$, $|f(n)-f| < \delta$.

Since $\bigg(1 + \frac{x}{n} \bigg)^n \to e^x$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $N_2$ s.t. $\forall n \ge N_2$,

$$\Bigg| \bigg(1 + \frac{x}{n} \bigg)^n - e^x \Bigg| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

for every $x \in [f-\delta, f+\delta]$.

Let $N = \max(N_1,N_2)$. Then, $\forall n \ge N$,

$$\Bigg| \bigg(1 + \frac{f(n)}{n} \bigg)^n - e^f \Bigg| \le \Bigg| \bigg(1 + \frac{f(n)}{n} \bigg)^n - e^{f(n)} \Bigg| + \Bigg| e^{f(n)} - e^f \Bigg| $$

by the triangle inequality.

$$ < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

$$ < \varepsilon$$

Hence, $\bigg(1 + \frac{f(n)}{n} \bigg)^n \to e^f$ as required.

---

**Note**: to prove this, we assumed $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$ exists. If it doesn't exist, then the RHS is not defined. Can the LHS be defined if the RHS is not?

We could, for instance, have $f(n) = -n$. Then, the LHS is identically zero, but the limit in the RHS is divergent so the RHS is not well-defined.

It's possible this could be solved by letting the RHS be: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{f(n)}$$ but I don't know if that's what you want.

---

It seems to me that user LegNaiB is saying it holds in general that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n,f(n)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} g(n,\lim_{m \to \infty}f(m))$$

where $f,g$ are arbitrary functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. This is false. Indeed, let $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$, $g(n) = nf(n)$. Then, the LHS is $1$ but the RHS is $0$.

Even a much less significant weakening of the assumptions still does not give the result. Let $g_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions converging uniformly $g_n \to g$ on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Then, does $g_n(f(n))$ converge to $g(\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n))$, if $g$ is not assumed to be continuous?

(In the question, $g_n(x) = \bigg(1+ \frac{x}{n} \bigg)^n$ and $g(x) = e^x$; here, $g$ is continuous.)

The answer is *no*. Let $g_n \equiv g$ be the indicator function of the non-positive reals, $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$. Then,

$$g_n(f(n)) \equiv 1$$

but

$$g(\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)) = 0$$

i.e. the result does not necessarily hold if $g$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is true for any function convergent $f(n)$. Why? Because you can remove duplicate limits.

For that let $f:=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)\in\mathbb{R}$, then:
\begin{align*}
e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)}&=e^f=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{f}{n}\right)^n \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\lim_{m\to\infty}f(m)}{n}\right)^n
\end{align*}
But then it doesn't matter if I first take the limit of $f(m)$ inside and then nevertheless take the limit of $n$. I can just take $n\to\infty$ directly, so we get the desired left side. Just the rate of approaching the limit will be faster when using $\lim_{m\to\infty}$ inside the brackets but the limit will not change.
$$
e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{f(n)}{n}\right)^n.
$$

Comment: Can we swap limits always??? Try lim (1+(1/n))^n by swaping, then we get 1 nah? So swaping works???

Comment: No, that swapping does not work. Also swapping is not the correct word, it is more "removing duplicate"

Comment: As $\lim_{n\to\infty}( \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$

Comment: I think that the result is right, but you have elided that you need the continuity of $\text{exp}$. I believe that this is not true otherwise.

Comment: Where did I use the continuity of exp? If I would've used $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{f(n)}=e^f$ that would use the continuity of exp but I didn't need that fact.

Comment: @LegNaiB I didn't say you used the continuity of $\text{exp}$, I said that you need it. I don't believe your proof is valid. Also, you have assumed the limit $f$ exists.

Comment: Yes, right, your answer and counter-example make totally sense. But assuming that the limit exists is somehow necessary as otherwise the result doesn't make sense, it is not true, e.g. with $f(n)=-2n$ we get oscillating $-1,1$ on the LHS and $0$ on the RHS in the limit or it is trivial, e.g. $f(n)\to \infty$, then LHS and RHS $\to \infty$

Comment: @LegNaiB Something similar happens with $f(n) = -n$ as I observed in my answer, if the limit is not assumed to exist. I just meant that I thought it was worthy of comment that the result breaks down if the limit does not exist.